# Referencing a union inside a structure using union tag gives incorrect address

Tags: c++, nested, structure, unions

I had a need to declare a union inside a structure as defined below:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int    m_DataType;
    DWORD  m_DataLen;
    union theData
    {
        char    m_Buff [_MAX_PATH];
        struct MyData m_myData;
    } m_Data;
};
```

Initially, I tried accessing the union data as follows (before I added the m_Data declaration):

```
MyStruct m_myStruct;

char* pBuff = m_myStruct.theData::m_Buff;
```

This compiles but returns to pBuff a pointer to the beginning of the MyStruct structure  which caused me to overwrite the m_DataType & m_DataLength members when I thought I was writing to the m_Buff buffer.

I am using Visual Studio 2008.  Can anyone explain this unexpected behavior?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be writing:

```
char *pBuff = m_myStruct.m_Data.m_Buff;
```

I wish I knew how it was compiling as written.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically my question.  Don't understand why that compiled or why it gave me the wrong offset.  I am now using m_myStruct.m_Data.m_Buff but I was just wanting to understand the compiler's reasoning for the previous access method.

Comment: Are you sure it was compiling?  Really sure?  Can you check again, because I can see no legitimate interpretation for what you wrote, and would point a finger at the compiler thinking 'bug'.

Comment: and AlanKley: I've compiled Alan's example with several versions of MSVC++ and it compiles without error right up through today's VC2010 release, and the result of the expression is exactly as Alan described - as nonsensical as it may be. All other compilers I've tried give an appropriate error message.

Comment: @Michael: thanks for the information - very intriguing (and more than a little surprising).

Comment: Thanks Michael. I'm glad I'm not going crazy.  Since other compilers flag the code as an error I'm going to chalk it up as as a VC compiler bug!

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't compile. GCC barfs at this code with :)

```
union.cpp:17: error: ‘MyStruct::theData’ is not a base of ‘MyStruct’
```

Comment: That would have been nice in VS2008, then I wouldn't have had to debug the problem and I would have been alerted to add the proper declaration to access the data with.  Thanks for checking it out.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you mean this?

```
char* pBuff = m_myStruct.m_Data.m_Buff;
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using now but I was seeking some insight on why the previous method worked the way it did.

Comment: Did the previous method compile? If so, can you print the pointer and edit your post?